# How to access headphone jack pins in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, 16.04

I'm running a Dell XPS 17 with a Realtek soundcard. There are usually 3 connector rings on a headphone jack (right headphone, left headphone, mic) and these are used to create music or record phone calls. How can I see realtime stats on their input/output for each of these input/output rungs? Specifically, I would like to be able to programatically obtain values for each headphone and mic -- Audacity won't cut it.

When I use hdajackretask, my soundcard seems to be a Realtek ALC3234 (other option is Intel Haswell HDMI). Here is the output of *sudo lshw | grep -A7 "Audio device"*

```
         description: Audio device
         product: 8 Series HD Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1b
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
         version: 04
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
```

Comment: Someone might be able to help you if you were to identify which Realtek sound card you have.  Perhaps the output of `sudo lshw | grep -A7 multimedia` or `sudo lshw | grep -A7 "Audio device"` would be helpful

Comment: Thanks, updated. I guess it's an Intel soundcard?

Comment: I would  prefer to do this in a way that was applicable regardless of a person's soundcard, but if that's not possible that's okay

Comment: I believe the Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller you are listing is an HDMI interface, so not your headphone jack. What exactly are you attempting to accomplish that you need to "programatically obtain values"? Please [edit] your question accordingly.